# How can I override a menu item in odoo 16

Tags: python, xml, menuitem, odoo-16

```
<record model="ir.ui.menu" id="hr_payroll.menu_hr_payroll_payslips ">
  <field name="name">Payroll</field>
</record>
```

I use this code that I saw in a video to change or override a name menu in odoo.
In this case I want to override the "Payslip" menu from payroll, and change the name payslip to payroll, 'cause my boss ask me that.

I tried it in odoo 15 and it works perfectly, but in odoo 16 doesn't work, don't know why. Please if someone can help me I would really appreciate it.

pd: In other case how can I change a menu item for other language, or change the language that I develop in odoo. I mean the code always will be in english, but what I want is that when I make a code and I using odoo in spanish, the menu item (in this case) change in odoo spanish and not only in odoo in english

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using English as your configured Odoo language it might be a localization issue.

Odoo 16 switched to a new translation system internally, now translatable fields are stored directly as JSON in Postgres.
Your code would only update the default (en_US) value but not the one for your language resulting in something like this being stored in the database:

```
{"en_US": "Payroll", "<your_locale>": "<Unaffected Payslip translation>"}
```

You could try looking into this solution instead:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51619850/22370090